# Exponential generating function of the sequence $\{na_n\}_n$ given a recursively defined sequence $\{a_n\}_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

> Find the exponential generating function of the sequence $\{na_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ where $\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is given by $a_0=-2,a_n=4a_{n-1}+3^n,n\ge 1.$

**My attempt:**

Let $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n.$ Then:
$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{na_n}{n!}x^n=xf'(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4a_{n-1}+3^n}{(n-1)!}x^n\\&=4x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}+3x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\\&=4x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n+3x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(3x)^n}{n!}\\&=4xf(x)+3xe^{3x}\\\implies xf'(x)&=4xf(x)+3xe^{3x}\\\implies f'(x)-4f(x)&=3e^{3x}.\end{aligned}$$

Now, I got stuck because I don't know how to solve this differential equation.  How can I solve this? Should I take a different route?

Comment: Can you solve the homogeneous version of this, $f'(x)-4f(x)=0$? Once you got the solution to the homogeneous equation, I suggest you look at the [method of variation of constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#First-order_equation).

Comment: @nejimban, ok, I got the following: $$\begin{aligned}f'(x)&=4f(x)\\\implies\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}&=4\\\implies\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx&=4x+C_1\\\implies\ln f(x)&=4x+C_1\\\implies f(x)&=Ce^{4x}.\end{aligned}$$ Now, I'll look at the thread.